# inconsistency in results with code calculating the distance traveled to integral of the function that computes acceleration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, calculus

so I have functions here
y = (t/8)^2
where y is the speed
and I move the object by this acceleration along the x axis
just like here in the code (attachment one)
and for time = 2, the object moved 28 units
that is, for the integral I calculated, the result should theoretically be the same, but it is not (calculations in the second appendix)
I think I have a bad understanding of how the program performs calculations in the update method or I've messed something up, so I'm asking an experienced person to correct me, thank you.

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float time = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private float distanceTraveled;
    [SerializeField] private bool Toggle = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!Toggle) return;
        time += Time.DeltaTime;

        float function = Mathf.Pow(time/8f,2);

        distanceTraveled += function;

        transform.Translate(
            new Vector3(
                function, 0f ,0f
            )
        );

        if (time >= 2) Toggle = false;
    }
}
```

[calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWyYL.png)

i've tried changing update to fixedUpdate, and i ran out of any further ideas.

EDIT (IMPORTANT)
ok guys, I added distanceTraveled += function * Time.deltaTime, and now it works, but can someone explain to me why???? after all, the function is evaluated for a variable that is independent of frames, so theoretically there should be no difference????

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.

Comment: alright, just did that

Comment: fixedDeltaTimeis for fixedupdate, not for update, you just want deltatime for update

Comment: Alr, sorry there I copied the script and I forgot I changed that part... it was initially time.deltatime, for this the result was 28, for time.fixeddeltatime and FixedUpdate() it was 2, so still not quite matching

Comment: The function itself is independent of frames, however the variable `time` is dependent on frames in this case.  Update runs once per frame, and the delta time is just the time since the last time update ran (last frame).  Since `time` is incremented using the time difference from frame to frame, it is thus dependent on frames.  btw, fixed delta time is whatever the physics time step is set to in project settings (default 0.02).  It doesn't change in the way that delta time does, it merely indicates the fixed time period between physics frames.